# How can I adapt this debian init.d script to work with CentOS 5?

Tags: debian, centos, centos5, init.d

I'm trying to get an lsyncd daemon running.  I installed the lsyncd RPM from epel, but it doesn't seem to come with an init.d script.  In the lsyncd repository, there's [this script](http://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/source/browse/package/debian/init.d) that works with Debian.  However, when I try to run this under CentOS, I get this message:

```
/etc/init.d/lsyncd: line 46: log_daemon_msg: command not found
```

How can I adapt this to work with CentOS?

Comment: From EPEL? Doubt it.

Comment: @Ignacio - You're right.  I'm not sure where I got it was from epel from.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

writing from scratch could be easier, depending on how complex the script is. the issue you're running into is this line in the script:

```
. /lib/lsb/init-functions
```

which loads all the functions for debian's startup scripts. in that is a function 'log_daemon_msg' which is where your problem is at.

you could look at the init-functions file to figure out what log_daemon_msg does, and replicate on CentOS, or you could step through the Debian script and see what is actually run (probably less than 5 lines of commands)

Answer (score 3):

`/usr/share/doc/initscripts-*/sysvinitfiles` contains a template you can use as a model for modifying the existing script or creating a new one.

Comment: In other words, it's easier just to write it from scratch using that template?  :-)

Comment: Probably, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Here is what I conjured up following the other recommendations, init.d tutorials, and the existing debian script found on the lsyncd googlecode site [link text](http://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/source/browse/package/debian/init.d?r=73).  Hope this helps others, just copy and paste!

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# lsyncd        This shell script takes care of starting and stopping
#               lsyncd (the Live Syncing (Mirror) Daemon)
#
# Author: Randy Reddekopp not-public@usask.ca
#
# chkconfig: 2345 13 87
# description: Lsyncd uses rsync to synchronize local directories with a remote \
#    machine running rsyncd. It watches multiple directories trees \
#    through inotify. The first step after adding the watches is to \
#    rsync all directories with the remote host, and then sync single \
#    file by collecting the inotify events. So lsyncd is a light-weight \
#    live mirror solution.
# pidfile: /var/run/lsyncd.pid
# processname: lsyncd

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions

PIDFILE="/var/run/lsyncd.pid"
LSYNCD_DIR="/usr/local/bin/"

start() {
        echo -n "Starting Live Syncing Daemon: "
        if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
                PID=`cat $PIDFILE`
                echo lsyncd already running: $PID
                exit 1;
        else
                cd $LSYNCD_DIR
                daemon ./lsyncd $OPTIONS
                RETVAL=$?
                echo
                [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/lsyncd
                return $RETVAL
        fi

}

stop() {
        echo -n "Shutting down Live Syncing Daemon: "
        echo
        killproc lsyncd
        echo
        rm -f /var/lock/subsys/lsyncd
        return 0
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        ;;
    stop)
        stop
        ;;
    status)
        status lsyncd
        ;;
    restart)
        stop
        start
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage:  {start|stop|status|restart}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
exit $?
```

Paste that code into /etc/init.d/lsyncd.

Change file permissions:

> chmod 755 /etc/init.d/lsyncd

In your /etc/lsyncd.conf.xml file you need to uncomment the "<pidfile .../>" node and set its filename attribute to "/var/run/lsyncd.pid".

Then you should be set to start the service!

> /sbin/service lsyncd start

Cheers,
Randy